# How to get the view's HTML in the Yaf controller action?

Tags: php, yaf-php-framework

I have a problem with [Yaf](http://yafdev.com/).

I make a view file ***a.phtml***, and the code in ***a.phtml*** is:

```
<p><?php echo 'abcd';?></p>
```

How can I get the HTML code `<p>abcd</p>` in a controller function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use the same code as well in a controller action. Alternatively, if you don't want to duplicate the code, you can include it. The PHP manual normally covers this basic kind of code usage, so you should perhaps make your question more clear what exactly you're asking programming wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

1. Inside your controller: `file_get_contents( $templatePath . '/a.phtml');`
2. Configure View. Then Use `$tpl = $this->getView()->render()`, see [Yaf_View_Simple::render()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.yaf-view-simple.php), to render the template content into a buffer variable.

Comment: $tpl = $this->getView()->render(); it work!! thank you!